# Getting field type information from FieldInfo object in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes

I'm looking at the **[FieldInfo object documentation for ArcGIS 10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000004v000000)** and am **not** seeing access for **field type (e.g. short, string, double)**.

Is it possible to get field type information from the FieldInfo object in ArcPy?

I know I can access the information from calling arcpy.ListFields(), but I want it through feature layer FieldInfo.

Comment: FieldInfo does not carry that information, Field does.

Comment: yeah thats what i figured.  Just frustrating to see an object called FieldInfo which does not have field type included.

Comment: FieldInfo appears to be an auxiliary class, designed for dealing with mapping fields on the fly.

Comment: I'm using it to filter out guid fields to patch a different bug with arcgis 10.2.  The bug is that it copy_features won't work if the feature layer has a GUID field.  I followed but with another post on a separate issue with detecting GUID fields using arcpy.ListFields()

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77440/create-list-of-guid-fields-using-arcpy-10-2

any ideas on this one?